# How to print selected (output) days only between two dates

Tags: sql, oracle

this codes output different days i.e. mon, tue and etc. in the week. For example the output could be mon only, or mon, tue, wed, thu and fri

```
school_days AS
  (
     SELECT to_char(trunc(sysdate ,'D') + LEVEL - sw.LEV_1, 'dy') as school_day
       FROM SCHOOL_WEEKS sw
    CONNECT BY LEVEL <= sw.LEV_2
  ),
```

this code output all dates between start date and end date

```
all_dates AS 
( 
    SELECT sw.sc_start_date + LEVEL-1 as weekday_date, to_char((sw.sc_start_date + LEVEL-1), 'DAY') as weekday_day
      FROM SCHOOL_WEEKS sw
   CONNECT BY sw.sc_start_date + LEVEL-1 <=  sw.sc_end_date
)
```

how do i print the selected days only between two dates?

```
SELECT * FROM all_dates
 WHERE to_char(weekday_date, 'dy') IN ('output of school_days only')
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `schoolday_DATE` to 1st query and then join them on `DATE` datatype values:

```
with
school_days AS
  (SELECT to_char(trunc(sysdate ,'D') + LEVEL - sw.LEV_1, 'dy') as school_day,
                  trunc(sysdate ,'D') + LEVEL - sw.LEV_1        as school_date
       FROM SCHOOL_WEEKS sw
    CONNECT BY LEVEL <= sw.LEV_2
  ),
all_dates AS 
  (SELECT to_char((sw.sc_start_date + LEVEL-1), 'DAY') as weekday_day,
                   sw.sc_start_date + LEVEL-1          as weekday_date           
      FROM SCHOOL_WEEKS sw
   CONNECT BY sw.sc_start_date + LEVEL-1 <=  sw.sc_end_date
  )
select a.*
from all_dates a join school_days s on s.school_date = a.weekday_day
order by a.weekday_date;
```